# Read tfrecords files from azure blob storage

Tags: azure, tensorflow, azure-blob-storage, tensorflow-datasets

I have some TFRecords files stored on Azure Blob storage. I wonder is there some way to read them directly using tensorflow's Dataset API.

The way I currently use is to download those tfreocrds to local file system and then read from via Dataset API. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go here is to construct [SAS tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) for your files and use the resulting urls to download the files in tensorflow. You can generate the tokens via Azure Portal if you only have a few files, or use something like the Azure CLI.

[image: az storage container generate-sas --connection-string]